# VS Code not logging to terminal when using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

I've been following tutorials to try and use VS Code.

When I run my code using Node, the Node window pops up and I can see it logging "go" and "go?" then it turns off when the timeout is reached. In the tutorials online the `console.logs` show in the VS Code terminal but are not for me.

Anyone know how to change it in the VS Code terminal? Thanks!

```js
console.log('go');
console.log('go?');
setTimeout(() => { console.log('timeout')}, 2000);
```

Trying to see the `console.log` outputs in the VS Code terminal.

Comment: Hello Matt!  Add your VS Code version here, just in case it becomes an important piece of data.  Also, perhaps any "suspicious" extensions you might have installed.  Suspicious how?  Ha!  You got me, I don't know for sure.  Perhaps extensions that touch the shell, or adds shells, or configures shells.